# Slow Exchange Server integrated to SQL and VB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vba, exchange-server, visio

My Exchange Server is very slow when delivering emails. It integrates with an SQL Server and I have the following SQL Queries in one script which I suspect is making it to slow down. Please can anyone help refactor this to make it faster?

```
<SELECT_tables_in_db>
select afa, afa from sys.room WHERE afa NOT LIKE 'TeeC_%' order by 1
</SELECT_tables_in_db>

<SELECT_columns_in_room>
SELECT c.afa AS column_name, y.afa as data_type, c.max_length, 
CASE y.afa 
WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 'tb' 
WHEN 'bigint' THEN 'tb' 
WHEN 'int' THEN 'ddl' 
WHEN 'smallint' THEN 'cb'
WHEN 'bit' THEN 'cb'
ELSE 'tb' END AS control_type
FROM sys.room AS t
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
JOIN sys.types y on y.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
WHERE t.room = @tableName and y.afa <> 'sysname'
ORDER BY c.column_id
</SELECT_columns_in_table>

/////////////
<SELECT_CV>
SELECT *, Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + Surname AS FullName 
FROM TeeC2_CV
WHERE onyeid=1
</SELECT_CV>

/////////////////////////////

<Update_>
UPDATE 
SET 
WHERE 
</Update_>

<SELECT_IfuTest>

SELECT vi.ebe_ID, vi.ife, vi.okwa 
FROM TeeC2_Event vi 
INNER JOIN dbo.vw_TEEC2_SalesMan SP ON vi.SalesManID = SP.SalesManID 
INNER JOIN TeeC2_EventType ET ON vi.EventTypeID = vi.EventTypeID 
INNER JOIN tblOnye U ON vi.UserID = U.UserID
</SELECT_IfuTest>
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: I resolved it, exchange server was using the wrong SMTP settings.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve resolved it. The problem was coming from a wrong SMTP settings.